# Is it good to use firebase database in android app when there is need to integrate the android app with unity based module?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

I am working on android project with my fellows and we will integrate unity based module with our android app so for this. I want to know which database is suitable SQLite or firebase? I am currently using SQLite but its very simple and  I think it will be difficult to work on it for complex tables data. If I will use firebase then I will it integrate with unity module or not?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase has Android, iOS, and Web SDKs; and a console where you can develop, manage, and monitor all the data and analytics from one place. Firebase real-time database is good for online presence and instant feed updates, while Firebase Firestore is good for user profile and other relational data records. Firebase has a UI SDK which makes it easy to interface with the resources in the project, and with tons of tutorials and starter projects it should be easy to quickly have a decent prototype to iterate upon. Since if you want your project on Massive scale, use their pricing calculator to figure if your expected scale will be covered by the free quota or if you go for the pay-as-you-go that the price is reasonable for your project.

cheers for your project!!